# Problem in refreshing picker's item xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have a problem in refreshing the picker's UI in my Android.

I have two picker Province and Town.
[image: see User Interface] 
[image: see Picker Bindings]

If I select an item in province picker the town picker should refresh it content base on the selected province.
[image: see Select Province] 
[image: see Selected Province e.g. Pangasinan] 
Therefore to do that I need to refresh my List of Town in my view model. which I successfully did each time I select a province.
[image: see Refreshing Town in View Model] 
[image: see Refreshing Town in MyLibrary] 
[image: see Refreshed List<Town> in View Model] 
The problem is the changes in my List of Town doesn't update or reflect on my Town's Picker when it run to my android emulator.

Any Idea?

[image: see Empty Town] 
One more thing, if I press the back button so to navigate to previous page. Then load the registration page again. The content of List of Town is successfully reflected to Town's Picker. It seems that it only bind my town picker in initialisation of my registration page. But once initialised it does not care whether you update the content of town in view model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please help us to help you properly: past your code in your question rather than providing print screen of your code. You also might want to read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

> the problem is the changes in my List of Town doesn't update or reflect on my Town's Picker

What method did you use to update the picker?  Try to detect the **SelectedIndexChanged** event of the province `Picker`, update the ItemsSource of town `Picker` in this method.

Check the code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Picker Title="select the Province" x:Name="ProvincePicker" ItemsSource="{Binding provinces}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ProvinceName}" SelectedIndexChanged="ProvincePicker_SelectedIndexChanged"></Picker>
    <Picker Title="select the Town" x:Name="TownPicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TownName}"></Picker>
</StackLayout>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public Page5()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var province_data = new ObservableCollection<_Province>()
    {
        //add the data
    };
    CityViewModel cityViewModel = new CityViewModel();
    cityViewModel.provinces = province_data;

    BindingContext = cityViewModel;
}

private void ProvincePicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CityViewModel viewModel = BindingContext as CityViewModel;

    var picker = sender as Picker;
    TownPicker.ItemsSource = viewModel.provinces[(picker).SelectedIndex].towns;
}
```

The code of model class

```
public class _Town
{
    public string TownName { get; set; }
}

public class _Province
{
    public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<_Town> towns { set; get; }
    public _Province()
    {
        towns = new ObservableCollection<_Town>();
    }
}

public class CityViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<_Province> provinces { get; set; }
    public CityViewModel()
    {
        provinces = new ObservableCollection<_Province>();
    }
}
```

[image]